# How to get the value of the attribute of a tag in xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I have an xml codelet which look like this..

```
<item>
<link href='http://webaddress'/>
</item>
```

The above code is stored in `$str`
I managed to obtain the 'link' tag by using

```
$item=simple_xml_load_string($str);
$link=$item->link;
```

But I don't know how to obtain the value of the attribute 'href' in the 'link' tag.Can anyone please help me?

Comment: look at this http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: **Thanks a lot** I have got it..

Comment: This questions also has been asked and answered before ;) - Please do not hesitate to use the search on this website :D